# Выйти из аккаунта если время истекло .Андроид

Tags: android

Стоит такая задача, осуществить выход из аккаунта в приложении андроид если реальная дата больше даты из переменной полученной из базы на сервере.
Ни могу разобраться как к этому подойти .
Получаю объект и записываю её в переменную `times`

```
                try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), object.getString("end_time"), 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }try {
                  times = response.getString("end_time");
```

Как мне теперь сравнить больше или равно если это не `int` ?
Может обернуть через `SimpleDateFormat` или преобразовать строку в `int`?

Comment: Перевести даты в timestamp и сравнить два значения

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю вы хотите сравнить обычную дату(например 27.09.2020) и timestamp (например 1601152104).

Для этого вы можете конвертировать дату в timestamp  и потом просто сравнить два числа:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24453081/12695243

Или наоборот timestamp в дату:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18930056/12695243

Сравнение двух дат в виде строк:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43250701/12695243